# ¿Cómo contar las palabras que hay en un texto en Java?

Tags: java

Necesito contar las palabras de un texto, pero teniendo en cuenta que el texto puede tener, saltos de línea, tabuladores, espacios duplicados entre palabras.

Es decir con el texto:

```
lorem impsum
armet amet, hello     world
```

con un `str.split(" ")` cuando la línea termina con `\n` no lo tiene en cuenta y me cuenta como si fuera una sola palabra `impsumarmet`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `"\\s+|\n"` como regexp para separar las palabras:

```
String text = "lorem impsum\narmet amet, hello     world";
System.out.println(text.split("\\s+|\n").length);
```

Salida:

```
6
```

Utiliza el operador pipe `|` para separar los caracteres tal como necesitas. Aquí otro ejemplo basado en tu cadena de ejemplo:

```
//la coma separa a amet y hello
String text = "lorem impsum\narmet amet,hello     world";
System.out.println(text.split("\\s+|\n|,").length);
```

Salida:

```
6
```

Ahora, si tu texto puede ser muy extenso, considera que `String#split` va a generar un arreglo con todas las distintas palabras que pueden haber en él y puede ser un arreglo muy grande en memoria. Si tienes la memoria como limitante, esto puede ser un problema. Una mejor estrategia sería consumir línea por línea y contar las palabras que hay en cada línea. Puedes utilizar un `Scanner` para ayudarte:

```
String texto = "texto con muchos\nsaltos de\nlínea";
Scanner scannerTexto = new Scanner(texto);
int contador = 0;
while(scannerTexto.hasNextLine()) {
    String linea = scannerTexto.nextLine();
    contador += linea.split("\\s+").length;
}
scannerTexto.close();
```

Pero si sabes que no habrán casos extraños como dos palabras juntas por un símbolo como `"amet,hello" entonces puedes reducir el código anterior para que lea mientras encuentre palabras:

```
while(scannerTexto.hasNext()) {
    scannerTexto.next();
    contador ++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Un método (sin usar REGEX) sería este el cual uso una versión similar, pero busqué la versión versión original de [@koool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864184/250260) la cual es esta:

```
public static int cuentaPalabras(String s){    
    int conteoPalabras = 0;    
    boolean palabra = false;
    int finDeLinea = s.length() - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        // Si el char is una letra, word = true.
        if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i != finDeLinea) {
            palabra = true;
            // Si el char no es una letra y aún hay más letras,
            // el contador continua.
        } else if (!Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && palabra) {
            conteoPalabras++;
            palabra = false;
            // última palabra de la cadena; si no termina con una no letra ,
        } else if (Character.isLetter(s.charAt(i)) && i == finDeLinea) {
            conteoPalabras++;
        }
    }
    return conteoPalabras;
}
```

Si ejecutamos el método anterior:

```
System.out.println("Palabras : " + cuentaPalabras("lorem impsum\narmet amet, hello     world"));
```

teniendo como salida:

```
Palabras : 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola para resolver tu duda te mando una captura y la publicacion del resultado del codigo espero y te sirva:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]